# Aggregate data use sql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the definition of the "exchange" `table`:

```
CREATE TABLE `exchange` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `volume` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=75032 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

About 209 records will store every 5 minutes.

How can I get this data structure?

```
rank, name, [volume,...](last 144 value), timestamp
```

I use this query:

```
SELECT `volume`
FROM `exchange`
WHERE `exchange`.`name` = 'binance'
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 144
```

Is there better way to get the data once? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, your method might be the best method, particularly if you have an index on `(name, timestamp)`.

You can try:

```
select e.volume
from exchange e
where e.timestamp >= (select e2.timestamp
                      from exchange e2
                      where e2.name = e.name
                      limit 1 offset 143
                     );
```

You can then aggregate the values as:

```
select e.name, sum(e.volume)
from exchange e
where e.timestamp >= (select e2.timestamp
                      from exchange e2
                      where e2.name = e.name
                      limit 1 offset 143
                     )
group by e.name;
```

Note:  In MySQL 8+, this is much simpler using `row_number()`:

```
select name, sum(volume)
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from exchange e
     ) e
where seqnum <= 144
group by name;
```